# Model Formset validation error

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to use a model formset with a custom form. I am using a different view for the GET and a different one for the POST functions, cause my html page consists of three different model formsets. My model is one

```
class Image(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor)
    date = models.DateField()
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    type = models.CharField(choices=TITLE,max_length=20)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='/pictures/', verbose_name='Image')



XRAY=[
    ('---------','---------'),
    ('PA Ceph', 'PA Ceph'),
    ('Lateral Ceph', 'Lateral Ceph'),
    ('Panoramic', 'Panoramic'),
]

class XrayImageForm(ModelForm):
    desc = forms.ChoiceField(choices=XRAY,required=True,  widget=Select(attrs={"class":"form-control input-sm"}))

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        exclude = ('customer', 'date','type', 'doctor',)
        widgets = {
            'desc':Select(attrs={'class':'form-control input-sm'}),
            'date': TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control input-sm datepicker input-append date',
                               'readonly':''}),
    }


    def save(self, commit=True):
        model = super(XrayImageForm, self).save(commit=False)
        model.desc = self.cleaned_data['desc'];

        if commit:
            model.save()

        return model

class InternalImageForm(ModelForm):
   desc = form.ChoiceField(....) # I have to do this cause different ModelForm has different choices in the desc field

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        exclude = ('customer',)
```

My get view is the following

```
def images(request, customer_id):
    images = Image.objects.all().order_by('date')
    pictures = {}
    for image in images:
        date = image.date.stformat("%d/%M/%Y")
        if not pictures.has_key(date):
            pictures[date] = {image.title:[image,]}
        else:
            if pictures[date].has_key(image.title):
                pictures[date][image.title].append(image)
            else:
                pictures[date] = {image.title:[image,]}
    xray_formset = modelformset_factory(Image, form=XrayImageForm,extra=4)
    xray_formset(queryset=Image.objects.none())
    internal_form = InternalImageForm()
    external_form = ExternalImageForm()
    args = dict(pictures=pictures, xray_formset=xray_formset, internal_form=internal_form, external_form=external_form, customer_id=customer_id)

    return render_to_response('customer/images.html', args, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I want to have them filtered by date and each date by a title (different Images could have the same title, and same date)

my post view

```
def upload_xray(request, customer_id):
    customer = Customer.objects.get(pk=customer_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        XrayFormSet = modelformset_factory(Image, form=XrayImageForm, extra=4)
        xray_formset = XrayFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        print xray_formset

    return redirect('customer-images', customer_id=customer_id)
```

But when I post the data i get a

```
ValidationError
Exception Value:[u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']
```

I don't do any actual saving, just wanted to see if it works. Also All fields are required but i don't fill all fields in the formset on my page (Suppose the user can upload 4 pictures but he might not want to. ). Hope I am making a bit of sense...Why is that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are including the [management form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#understanding-the-managementform) in your template.

```
{{ xray_formset.management_form }}
```

If that doesn't work, then update your question to include your template.

Comment: Thank you it works. But it won't validate now. I am presenting 5 forms formset but when only one is used, the others won't validate.Is this the supposed behaviour?

Comment: If the posted data matches the initial data, then Django will allow empty forms. If the values for the empty forms have changed, then Django will validate them.

Comment: Initial values are empty still won't let me

Comment: It's definitely possible to submit only one form on a formset, but you've not given me enough information to help you. The template/post data show what's going on.

Comment: I updated the class of one of the modelforms and the Image so you have a better idea

Comment: I think I got it :) XRAY first tuple needs to have a "" value. I had a ("---------","----------") when it needed to be ("", "---------"). It doesn't give me any errors now

Comment: Glad you found the problem :)